# Sublime Text displaying CSS & Javascript in a single line

Tags: javascript, css, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm facing a problem in Sublime Text where all my CSS & Javascript are displayed in a single line. So far I have no problem in displaying HTML.

**Currently:**

```
body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-family:"Open Sans",sans-serif}.bold.btn,.sbold.btn{letter-spacing:0}
```

**I wish to display it in a structural form:**

```
body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
     font-family:"Open Sans",sans-serif
}

.bold.btn,.sbold.btn{
     letter-spacing:0
}
```

I have searched through online but failed to find any solution. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you looked into some plugin? If it is just for a single file, you could also just paste into any online formatter and paste it back into your file. https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CSS%20Format

Comment: I assume you are referring to files that you open? It's possible that those files were minified, and/or you will need an additional plugin to reformat them.

Comment: Thank you so much!! You save my day!! Btw is there any existing formatter for Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a beautifier plugin from https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify . This allows you to reformat text and also comment 'beautify ignore' can be used for ignoring the reformatting of text.
In this way the css and javascript codes can be split into different lines and preferable reformatting of text can be done.
More instructions about installing and usage of the plugin can be found in the above link.

Comment: I just installed and tried. It works like magic :) Thank you so much.